# VSCode: Open new terminal as part of task?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Visual Studio Code was just updated to allow running a task and having them open in a split terminal. This is great, however I'm looking for one more thing to make this perfect.

I would like to be able to open a total of 3 terminals via a task. One for my NPM build, one for my backend MAVEN build, and a third that is just a blank new terminal I can use for git commands when needed.

I can't seem to find a way to tell VSC to run a task that just opens a new terminal ready to use without providing it a command. I would even settle with giving it a simple command like "node -v" just to start it out, as long as that panel is still usable after. Right now it wants to close it after it has ran.

Here is my task setup: I have one task setup as the build task that depends on two others. I envision adding a third one to that which would just open the new terminal:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Run Maven and NPM",
      "dependsOn": [ "maven", "npm" ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true,
      },
    },
    {
      "label": "maven",
      "command": "...",
      "type": "shell",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "group": "build"
      },
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/server"
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "npm",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "ng serve --port 4203 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "group": "build"
      },
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/client-APS"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following should work:

```
{
    "type": "process",
    "label": "terminal",
    "command": "/bin/bash",  // <-- your shell here
    "args": [
        "-l"  // login shell for bash
    ],
    "problemMatcher": [],
    "presentation": {
        "echo": false,  // silence "Executing task ..."
        "focus": true,
        "group": "build",  // some arbitrary name for the group
        "panel": "dedicated"
    },
    "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
    }
}
```

I was trying to achieve something very similar when I stumbled my way into this solution: Here, I'm auto-launching (and setting the focus on) the terminal when the folder is opened in vscode -- and further tasks that share the same `presentation.group` gets placed in split terminals when they're run (with new vs. reused splits depending on their `presentation.panel`)

(The runOptions bit is superfluous for your case, but I'm keeping it in case it is helpful for someone)

Note: For this example, you may or may not need the `-l` option depending on your settings for `terminal.integrated.shell*`, `terminal.integrated.automationShell*` and `terminal.integrated.inheritEnv` -- [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/70248) issue has some discussion on what is involved in setting up the shell environment.